# How I can make persp-mode save my workspace on every change?

Tags: persp-mode

I'm using `persp-mode` to save my workspace/desktop/opened buffers on Emacs close and restore it on Emacs start (configured via `doom-emacs`. However, sometimes I can't properly shutdown Emacs (e.g. laptop's sleep failure, empty battery etc.), so I would like persp-mode to save the workspace on every buffer list change. I did not find an appropriate configuration option in the `persp-mode.el`, but it's probably hackable, but I have no clue where to start looking for the right hook.

So how can I save my desktop on every change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `(add-hook 'doom-switch-buffer-hook #'doom-save-session)`, however, serializing your workspace is a fairly expensive process and will add a notable delay to your everyday use of Emacs/Doom.

A less intrusive alternative might be to save on a timer, e.g.

```
;; runs after 10s of idle time
(run-with-idle-timer 10 t #'doom-save-session)

;; or every 10s, period
(run-at-time 10 t #'doom-save-session)
```

Combined with a timer, a third possibility is to save only when your battery is low, using the battery.el package (built into Emacs):

```
(defun save-on-low-battery ()
  (require 'battery)
  (let* ((data (and battery-status-function (funcall battery-status-function)))
         (percentage (car (read-from-string (cdr (assq ?p data))))))
    (when (and (numberp percentage)
               (<= percentage battery-load-critical))
      (doom-save-session))))

(run-at-time 10 t #'save-on-low-battery)
```

Some other potential hook candidates:

- `doom-switch-window-hook`
- `window-configuration-change-hook`
- `focus-out-hook`

---

Hope that helps!

Comment: Running on timer is excellent, thanks (for the answer and for `doom-emacs`)!